# Token generator for Valve Data Format parser in Java

Tags: java, parsing

I'm looking to parse a reduced subset of the Valve Data Format (VDF). It is similar to JSON, allowing representation of key-value collections (maps) with arbitrary recursion. As a small example:

```
"root"
{
    "key1"      "value1"
    "key2"      "value2"
    "key3"
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm taking on only a subset of the language (no comments; all keys and values enclosed in quotation marks; no escape sequences). Below is the code I've written to tokenize and iterate over input of the above form:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Iterator;

class TokenIterator implements Iterator<String>, Iterable<String>, AutoCloseable
{
    private static final int EOF = -1;
    private static final int BUFFER_SZ = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
    private static final String LPAREN = "{";
    private static final String RPAREN = "}";

    private final Reader reader;
    private final StringBuilder sb;
    private int ch;

    private TokenIterator(Reader reader, StringBuilder sb, int ch)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.sb = sb;
        this.ch = ch;
    }

    static TokenIterator forPath(Path path)
    {
        try
        {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path.toFile()), BUFFER_SZ);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            return new TokenIterator(reader, sb, reader.read());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        try 
        {
            while ((ch == '\n' || ch == '\r' || ch == '\t' || ch == ' '))
            {
                ch = reader.read();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
        return ch != EOF;
    }

    @Override
    public String next()
    {
        try
        {
            String result;
            switch (ch)
            {
                case '"':
                    done:
                    do
                    {
                        ch = reader.read();
                        switch (ch) {
                            case EOF:
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Reached EOF while reading quoted string");
                            case '"':
                                ch = reader.read();
                                result = sb.toString();
                                sb.setLength(0);
                                break done;
                            default:
                                sb.append(ch);
                        }
                    }
                    while (true);
                    break;
                case '{':
                    result = LPAREN;
                    break;
                case '}':
                    result = RPAREN;
                    break;
                default:
                    String message = String.format("Unexpected char '%x' at beginning of token", ch);
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
            }
            ch = reader.read();
            return result;
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception
    {
        reader.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TokenIterator it = forPath(Paths.get("items_game.txt"));
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (String s : it) {}
        System.out.printf("Token iteration time: %d", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }

}
```

All constructive comments are welcome, but I'm most interested in improving performance. It's taking around 70ms to iterate through a 3.66MB, ~131k line file of this type on my machine (i7-7700HQ 2.8GHz processor, 16GB system memory), which I find disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the older, legacy `java.io.File` and `java.io.FileReader` classes for opening a newer `java.nio.file.Path` object.  The `nio` stands for "new IO", and can make use of high-efficiency byte-buffers and operating system calls for file reading and writing.  You may (or may not) see an improvement if you use the newer [`Files.newBufferedReader(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path)) method from `java.nio.file` to open the file.

(You cannot specify the buffer size using the `newBufferedReader()` method, but your 4MB buffer was likely not helping you since the operating system would limit itself to transferring the drive's block-size memory chunks anyway.)

The `TokenIterator` constructor is `private`, and only called from `forPath(...)`.  The `forPath(...)` method does preparatory work for the constructor, creating a `BufferedReader`, `StringBuilder` and reading one character from the reader to prime the `TokenIterator`.  These are all internal details which could be hidden completely inside the constructor:

```
private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public TokenIterator(Path path) {
    try {
       reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
       ch = reader.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

`TokenIterator` is declared as an `AutoCloseable` resource, but you are not taking advantage of that in your `main` function, so possibly leaking a resource:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (TokenIterator it = new TokenIterator(Paths.get("item_games.txt"))) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (String s : it) { /* no-op */ }

        System.out.printf("Token iteration time: %d", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }  // TokenIterator is auto-closed here.

}
```